# Multi Module Scala Project Include Conf Files from other modules

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multi module scala application that I use to do ML training. I have a core module that contains some generic configuration which I would like to add in the other modules that depends on the core module.

All my configuration files are located in the resources folder and my project structure looks like this:

```
core
  src
    main
     resources
       application.conf
mod1
  src
    main
     resources
       application.conf
mod2
  src
    main
     resources
       application.conf
```

So I would like to have in my mod1 and mod2 module's application.conf file, this as the first line:

```
include core/application.conf
```

So that I can override some of the settings from there. How do I do this? For example., here is the build.sbt sample on how I define my module mod1:

```
// Define Sub Modules and its settings
lazy val mod1 = (project in file(MODULE_NAME_CLEANSE)).dependsOn(core% "compile->compile;test->test", config)
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    enablingCoverageSettings,
    dockerSettings(),
    name := MODULE_1,
    description := "Clean the incoming data for training purposes"
  )
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Assuming you are using Lighbend's config library.*

Once built/deployed, your 2 modules will each have in their classpath the `application.conf` file from core module and the one from the said module. Both will be loaded but you cannot guarantee the order.

The recommended way is to name it `reference.conf` file in your core module instead of `application.conf` because that way you are sure that `reference.conf` is loaded with lower priority than `applicayion.conf`.

See https://github.com/lightbend/config#standard-behavior :

> The convenience method ConfigFactory.load() loads the following (first-listed are higher priority):
>
> - system properties
> - application.conf (all resources on classpath with this name)
> - application.json (all resources on classpath with this name)
> - application.properties (all resources on classpath with this name)
> - reference.conf (all resources on classpath with this name)
>
> The idea is that libraries and frameworks should ship with a reference.conf in their jar. Applications should provide an application.conf

Comment: Ok, but how do I include the reference.conf in my sub modules? Just include reference.conf?

Comment: You don't have to include it explicitly. All `reference.conf` files found in the classpath will be loaded.

Comment: You can read https://github.com/lightbend/config#how-to-handle-defaults as well